# EMGU -" Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I've got the message above, while I'm trying to run my algorithm on more than 26 frames.

My program is in C#, with my experience with OpenCV in java(Android) I know that I need to release the matrix, do I need to do it here also?

this is the part with the problem:

```
 private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
            for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_SIZE; i++)
            {
                ColorImage = _Capture.QueryFrame();
                if (ColorImage != null)
                {
                    GrayImage = ColorImage.Convert<Gray, float>();
                    toolStripProgressBar1.Value = i;
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        Max_G2 = new Image<Gray, float>(GrayImage.Width, GrayImage.Height);
                        mainimage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(GrayImage.Width, GrayImage.Height);
                    }
                    FindMax(GrayImage.Copy());
                }
                else
                {
                    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "The video is too short!";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

private void FindMax(Image<Gray, float> CurrGray)
        {

            Image<Gray, float> TempImg = new Image<Gray, float>(CurrGray.Width, CurrGray.Height);

            Matrix<float> kernel1 = new Matrix<float>(new float[1, 2] { { -1, 1 } });
            Matrix<float> kernel2 = new Matrix<float>(new float[2, 1] { { -1 }, { 1 } });

            Point anchor = new Point(0, 0);

            CvInvoke.cvFilter2D(CurrGray, TempImg, kernel1, anchor);
            CvInvoke.cvFilter2D(CurrGray, CurrGray, kernel2, anchor);
            TempImg = TempImg.Pow(2);
            CurrGray = CurrGray.Pow(2);

            CurrGray = CurrGray.Add(TempImg);
            CurrGray = CurrGray.Pow(0.5);

            Max_G2._Max(CurrGray);
        }
```

1 more thing, I already tried to dispose all the matrix and images, but it doesn't work for me.
What do I miss here?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1: ( Code with dispose)**

```
private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_SIZE; i++)
            {

                ColorImage = _Capture.QueryFrame();
                if (ColorImage != null)
                {
                    GrayImage = ColorImage.Convert<Gray, float>();

                    toolStripProgressBar1.Value = i;
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        Max_G2 = new Image<Gray, float>(GrayImage.Width, GrayImage.Height);
                        TempImg = new Image<Gray, float>(GrayImage.Width, GrayImage.Height);
                        mainimage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(GrayImage.Width, GrayImage.Height);
                    }
                    FindMax(GrayImage);

                    ColorImage.Dispose();
                    ColorImage = null;
                    GrayImage.Dispose();
                    GrayImage = null;

                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
                else
                {
                    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "The video is too short!";
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

private void FindMax(Image<Gray, float> CurrGray)
        {



            Matrix<float> kernel1 = new Matrix<float>(new float[1, 2] { { -1, 1 } });
            Matrix<float> kernel2 = new Matrix<float>(new float[2, 1] { { -1 }, { 1 } });

            Point anchor = new Point(0, 0);

            CvInvoke.cvFilter2D(CurrGray, TempImg, kernel1, anchor);
            CvInvoke.cvFilter2D(CurrGray, CurrGray, kernel2, anchor);

            TempImg.Pow(2);
            CurrGray.Pow(2);

            CurrGray.Add(TempImg);
            CurrGray.Pow(0.5);

            Max_G2._Max(CurrGray);

            CurrGray.Dispose();
            CurrGray = null;

        }
```

Comment: Well, by a quick look at your methods, FindMax keeps assigning new images to CurrGray without disposing the previous ones, which may be causing the issue. What do you mean it didn't work when you tried disposing them?

Comment: I'm adding the code with all of the disposes.

Comment: Another thing, This code running well in other computer. It's look like that the garbage collector doesn't works well.

Comment: You should try checking for null before disposing the images. After you dispose CurrGray, GrayImage might be already disposed along with it (though this depends on how EMGU handles its images. C# Image has this issue, which is why I mention it)

Comment: I found a solution!
but I'm not sure why, If I don't use the For loop and instead I create event like this : `Application.Idle += ProcessFrame1;` and inside the event I limit the "For" loop condition, then it's works fine.